# How can I tell if nginx is caching responses with (shared) max age, public?

Tags: caching, symfony, nginx, symfony-2.1, http-caching

Is it possible to know whether the response I got, is new (I'm the first who made that request) or came out from the cache (someone else, or me, has already made that request and the cache is fresh).

I have access to everything, but I can't find where to see the hits/misses.

I can't see anything in the headers either, that indicate the age of the response (only the max age).

When I use Symfony2's AppCache instead of nginx cache, I can see an Age header. Should nginx be adding that header too?

Comment: Have a look at this ticket :  http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/146

Comment: @machour I found this: add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;. Seems to work fine, but only for caching I defined from nginx (eg: fastcgi_cache_valid 200 302 1h;). When I'm sending responses with cache headers from my backend I only get MISS and the cache dir is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found [this](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,226331,226337#msg-226337):

```
add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
```

Seems to work fine.